# In mysql, is it possible to add a column based on values in one column?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql table data which has following columns

```
+-------+-----------+----------+
|a      | b         | c        |
+-------+-----------+----------+
| John  | 225630096 |      447 |
| John  | 225630118 |      491 |
| John  | 225630206 |      667 |
| John  | 225630480 |     1215 |
| John  | 225630677 |     1609 |
| John  | 225631010 |     2275 |
| Ryan  | 154247076 |     6235 |
| Ryan  | 154247079 |     6241 |
| Ryan  | 154247083 |     6249 |
| Ryan  | 154247084 |     6251 |
+-------+-----------+----------+
```

I want to add a column `d` based on the values in `a` and `c` (See expected table below). Values in `a` is the name of the subject, `b` is one of its attribute, and `c` another. So, if the values of `c` are within 15 units of each other for each subject assign them a same cluster number (for example, each value in `c` for `Ryan` is within 15 unit, so they all are assigned 1), but if not assign them a different value as in for `John`, where each row gets a different value for `d`.

```
+-------+-----------+----------+---+
|a      | b         | c        |d  |
+-------+-----------+----------+---+
| John  | 225630096 |      447 | 1 |
| John  | 225630118 |      491 | 2 |
| John  | 225630206 |      667 | 3 |
| John  | 225630480 |     1215 | 4 |
| John  | 225630677 |     1609 | 5 |
| John  | 225631010 |     2275 | 6 |
| Ryan  | 154247076 |     6235 | 1 |
| Ryan  | 154247079 |     6241 | 1 |
| Ryan  | 154247083 |     6249 | 1 |
| Ryan  | 154247084 |     6251 | 1 |
+-------+-----------+----------+---+
```

I am not sure if this could be done in mysql, but if not i would welcome any python based answers as well, in that case, working on this table as cdv format.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really sure how i would use trigger here, any similar examples?

Comment: your specification is insuficient. What happens for John<->445 and for Ryan<->7000

Comment: John 445 will be assigned as 1 as its within 15 units of 447, and for Ryan 7000, it will be assigned as 2 as its not within 15 units of any of the numbers for Ryan...Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a query with variables:

```
SELECT a, b, c,
       CASE WHEN @last_a != a THEN @d:=1
            WHEN (@last_a = a) AND (c>@last_c+15) THEN @d:=@d+1
            ELSE @d END d,
       @last_a := a,
       @last_c := c
FROM
  tablename, (SELECT @d:=1, @last_a:=null, @last_c:=null) _n
ORDER BY a, c
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b559/1).

**Explanation**

I'm using a join between `tablename` and the subquery `(SELECT ...) _n` just to initialize some variables (d is initialized to 1, @last_a to null, @last_c to null).

Then, for every row, I'm checking if the last encountered a -the one on the previous row- is different than the current a: in that case set @d to 1 (and return it).

If the last encountered a is the same as the current row and c is greater than the last encountered c + 15, then increment @d and return its value.

Otherwise, just return d without incrementing it. This will happen when a has not changed and c is not greater than the previous c+15, or this will happen at the first row (because @last_a and @last_c have been initialized to null).

To make it work, we need to order by a and c.

Comment: This works :), but i don't understand how. It would be great if you can elaborate little bit. Thanks

Comment: @mshakya i added an explanation, please see my updated answer, hope everything is clear

Comment: Thank you much. I think this makes much sense now.

Comment: please note that this solution only works if the table is sorted by a, c, before-hand. ORDER BY is only applied after the records are computed.